# I need to change the images shape to trapezoid without cropping the image

Tags: html, css

```css
.Div {
  border: double;
  height: 400px;
  width: 325px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 13%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 93%);
}
```

```html
<div class="Div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.Div {
  border: double;
  height: 400px;
  width: 325px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 13%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 93%);
  transform: rotate(90deg); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can create div tag and apply CSS on it

```
style="background-image:url('img.png');background-size:12px";
```

and Also can check the div style.